# Can we distinguish the clothespins on a clothesline?

Tags: probability

I'm doing some questions about probability these days. One of them is that suppose we have N same clothespins on a clothesline. And I wonder if these clothespins are distinguishable? One of my friends' opinion is only the clothespins on the both ends of the clothesline are indistinguishable and I think they are all distinguishable. Which one is true?

Comment: Which possible ways of distinguishing the pins do you consider?

Comment: I think if I put the clothespins on the clothesline one by one. Each one is on the right side of the former one, then we can specify each clothespin by counting how many clothespins on the left side of the spin.

Comment: Using the word same would imply to me that the clothespins are identical.  The locations may differ, allowing you to distinguish one from another when they are on the line, but if they were all in a pile you could not.

Comment: @RossMillikan yes that's what I mean

Comment: I wonder if those pins at the both ends are indistinguishable. If so, I must multiply my number of states by factor 2.

Comment: You might get a better answer if you told us the original probability question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the word same would imply to me that the clothespins are identical. The locations may differ, allowing you to distinguish one from another when they are on the line, but if they were all in a pile you could not.  As an example, imagine you have four clothespins to hang on a line and can hang them right side up or upside down.  If the pins are indistinguishable, there are $2^4=16$ ways to do it, because each one has $2$ possibilities.  If they are distinguishable, you need to multiply by the $4!=24$ orders you can put them in.